# How to condition table from two tables in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html

my result is almost completed. Just that there's a small area which is displaying not what I want. I have a dropdownlist with categories in it, and wish to display the details stored in each category in my table.

**Code for Model:**

```
namespace Mp.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    public partial class Content
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Link is required!", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        public string Link { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Category is required!", AllowEmptyStrings=false)]
        public string Category { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Code for Controller:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Mp.Models;
using System.Data.Entity.Validation;
using System.Net;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace Mp.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Contents()
        {

                ContentsEntities db = new ContentsEntities();

                var details = from d in db.Contents
                              select d;

                var category = from c in db.Categories
                               select c;


                return View((details).ToList());
        }   

    }
}
```

**Code for View:**

```
@{
  @model IEnumerable<Mp.Models.Content>
  ViewBag.Title = "Contents";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutMember.cshtml";
}

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Contents</h2>


    @using(@Html.BeginForm())
    {
        if(User.IsInRole("Admin"))
       {
        <div align="right">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" style="border:none">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" onclick="window.location = '@Url.Action("Index", "Contents")';"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
       }
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        @foreach (var category in Model)
        {
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#@category.Category">@category.Category</a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="@category.Category" class="panel-collapse collapse ">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <ul>
                            @foreach (var details in Model)
                            {
                                    if (details.Category == category.Category)
                                    {
                                        <li><a href="http://@details.Link" target="_blank">@Html.DisplayFor(dismsg => details.Link)</a></li>
                                    }
                            }
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
   </div>
        <br />
        if(User.IsInRole("Admin"))
        {
        <div>
            <input type="button" value="Edit Content Page" onclick="window.location = '@Url.Action("Index", "Contents")';" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">
        </div>
        }
        }
</body>
```

**Screenshot of output:**
[image]

The header of the table is the same as the dropdownlist categories. However when I create the second input into one of the category, it will duplicate the same header at the bottom. However, the details in the category will still be displayed at the original table.

**Screenshot for problem output:**
[image]

As you can see "DayToDayOperations" is being created at the bottom again, but the "secondhyperlink.com" is displayed at the top. Please help me in correcting my view's code. I'm guessing I didn't do my `foreach` clause properly.

**Screenshot for drop down list:**
[image]

Comment: Your question is very unclear (partly because of your terminlogy - you don't have a dropdownlist (a `<select>` tag) - so hard to understand what your referring to). Are you saying that each category can have multiple links?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes, each category can have multiple link. I've just added the screenshot of my drop-down list. I understand the link will be added to the table of the same category, but do not understand why it is creating another duplicate table at the bottom.

Comment: Because that's what your code is doing :). Based on what your have shown, your view model should have 2 properties (say) `string Name` and `IEnumerable<string> Links` then its simply `foreach (var category in Model) { @category.Name foreach (var link category.Links) { @link }}` But I suspect the real issue is your database structure is wrong anyway.

Comment: @StephenMuecke does showing you a screenshot of my database helps?

Comment: Showing your `Category` model will help (what is the relationship between `Content` and `Category`?) And why does your `Contents()` method get a collection of categories when you don't even use it (a lot of your code does not make sense)